# How do I extract the membrane from an egg?

Tags: eggs, hard-boiled-eggs

I have heard eggshell membranes are good for your joints.

But every time when I peel a boiled egg, the membrane is stuck to the shell.

How do I get the membrane out and eat it?

Comment: I don't know that it would be very useful, but if you soak an egg in vinegar you can dissolve the shell leaving just the membrane.

Comment: @sourd'oh wha?? I've never heard of that. Just regular vinegar? How long does it need to soak? Could I do that for deviled eggs?

Comment: @Jolenealaska It's usually more of a kids science experiment thing. I don't remember exactly how long it takes, but I think is a couple days. [Naked Egg](http://imaginationstationtoledo.org/content/2011/04/how-to-make-a-naked-egg/)

Comment: @Jolenealaska: If you use 25% regular vinegar the shell should be dissolved within one day (if I remember rightly). Months ago I did [this](https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/t31.0-8/1167081_10201636107519579_291663948_o.jpg).

Comment: That is cool...now I really *do* want to experiment.

Comment: Though it makes your egg taste of vinegar @Jolenealaska

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably find it easier to crack a raw egg and then peel the membrane from inside. Maybe use some tweezers to get started.

Comment: Thanks, its much easier to extract from raw egg and a cooked one.